# When practicing Promise in JS, the result is unexpected,

Tags: javascript, promise

```js
function sendOne() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    QF.get("./data/1.json", {}, function(data) {
      if (data.error === 0) {
        resolve(data);
      } else {
        reject(data);
      }
    })
  })
}

function sendTwo() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    QF.get("./data/2.json", {}, function(data) {
      if (data.error === 0) {
        resolve(data);
      } else {
        reject(data);
      }
    })
  })
}

function sendThree() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    QF.get("./data/3.json", {}, function(data) {
      if (data.error === 0) {
        resolve(data);
      } else {
        reject(data);
      }
    })
  })
}

var p1 = sendOne();


p1
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log("Succeeded for the first time");
    return sendTwo();
  }, function(data) {
    console.log("Failed for the first time")

  })
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log("Succeeded the second time");
    return sendThree();
  }, function(data) {
    console.log("Failed the second time")

  })
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log("Succeeded the third time");
  }, function(data) {
    console.log("Failed for the third time")
  })
```

All three requests are wrong, and they should all output wrong results. Why is the second request successful?
In my understanding, after the first request fails, it will be executed a second time, but it will also fail the second time. But the problem now is that it will succeed the second time

Comment: In the three request files, error is equal to 1

Comment: Please be clearer about what output this code produces, since we can't run it ourselves. Preferably in English, not Chinese.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

```
p1
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log("Succeeded for the first time");
    return sendTwo();
  }, function(data) {
    console.log("Failed for the first time")
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log("Succeeded the second time");
    return sendThree();
  }, function(data) {
    console.log("Failed the second time")
  })
```

If `p1` fails, the error handler `console.log("Failed for the first time")` is being executed. This has *caught* the failure and prevented it from propagating. That's what error handlers/`.catch` clauses are for in promise chains: to stop error propagation and allow the chain to continue. Which it then does with the next `.then`, which prints `console.log("Succeeded the second time")`, regardless of whether `sendTwo()` was even called or not.

Comment: After the first request fails, what is the success of the second request? Are you saying that after the first failure, the subsequent request will be ignored and the output will be successful?

Comment: It goes `p1.then(..., HERE).then(HERE, ...)`. The success handler of `p1.then` is never entered and `sendTwo` is never called.

Comment: You probably want something like `p1.then(() => console.log('1 success'), e => console.log('1 fail')).then(() => sendTwo())` to make sure `sendTwo` is called regardless of the success of the first.

Comment: According to your statement, why did the output fail the third time? It should not be `p1.then(..., HERE).then(HERE, ...)`

Comment: Because the `sendThree` is called and returned and it fails, so it goes into the closest subsequent error handler in the chain.

Comment: In general: when something succeeds, it goes to the *closest subsequent success handler*, and if something fails, it goes to the *closest subsequent error handler*. Those handlers will then inject their return value into the chain, and this rule applies again from there.

Answer (score 1):

```
p1 // <- promise is rejected, go to next rejected handler
  .then(function(data) {                    //   |
    // ...                                  //   |
  }, function(data) { // <-----------------------+
    console.log("Failed for the first time")
    // no errors, successful undefined return value, go to next fulfilled handler
  })                                        //   |
  .then(function(data) { // <--------------------+
    console.log("Succeeded the second time");
    return sendThree(); // <- promise is rejected, go to next rejected handler
  }, function(data) {                       //   |
    // ...                                  //   |
  })                                        //   |
  .then(function(data) {                    //   |
    // ...                                  //   |
  }, function(data) {  // <----------------------+
    console.log("Failed for the third time")
  })
```

If the reject handler doesn't throw an error or return rejected promise the result is considered a success, therefore the next `.then()` will trigger the fulfilled handler. If you want to keep the reject handler chain going you have to re-throw the exception.

```
p1 // <- promise is rejected, go to next rejected handler
  .then(function(data) {                       //   |
    // ...                                     //   |
  }, function(data) { // <--------------------------+
    console.log("Failed for the first time")
    throw data; // <- causes the current promise to be rejected, go to next rejected handler
  })                                           //   |
  .then(function(data) {                       //   |
    // ...                                     //   |
  }, function(data) { // <--------------------------+
    console.log("Failed the second time")
    throw data; // <- causes the current promise to be rejected, go to next rejected handler
  })                                           //   |
  .then(function(data) {                       //   |
    // ...                                     //   |
  }, function(data) { // <--------------------------+
    console.log("Failed for the third time")
  })
```

Instead of `throw data` you could also use `return Promise.reject(data)` depending on your preference.

Alternatively you could place a single rejected handler at the end.

```
p1 // <- promise is rejected, go to the next reject handler
  .then(function(data) {                           //   |
    console.log("Succeeded for the first time");   //   |
    return sendTwo();                              //   |
  })                                               //   |
  .then(function(data) {                           //   |
    console.log("Succeeded the second time");      //   |
    return sendThree();                            //   |
  })                                               //   |
  .then(function(data) {                           //   |
    console.log("Succeeded the third time");       //   |
  }, function(data) { // <------------------------------+
    console.log("One, two or three failed.")
  })
```